# Swiperjs 100% width bug when inside grid

Tags: html, css, width, swiper.js

I am facing an issue while using SwiperJS inside a grid. When I place the Swiper wrapper inside a  with display: grid, the wrapper overflows by 100%. I have provided a link to my JSFiddle example. If you remove the CSS, you will see that everything is normal. However, when I add the grid, that's when the problem occurs.

Thank you.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/strix1337/ozwdj0kr/6/)

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>

<div class="item-grid">
  <div>
    <div class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 6,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
  });
</script>

.item-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 24px;
}
```

Comment: To have two equal rows?  My grid has nothing to do with the slider that's why I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the min-width of the grid item containing the swiper to 100%.

```css
.item-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 24px;
}

.item-grid > :first-child {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<div class="item-grid">
  <div>
    <div class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 6,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex instead of grid.

```
.item-grid {
   display: flex;
}
.item-grid > div {
   width: 50%;
}
```

Use this style.

Comment: Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/g034tvf9/